# Printing pointer variables

Tags: go

I created 2 Vertex objects below- q & q.

Now, when I print the pointer variable q = &Vertex, I expected it to be the memory address, why is it printing the - &{1,2}

Output:

```
{1 2} &{1 2}
```

Program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

var (
    p = Vertex{1, 2}  // has type Vertex
    q = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(p, q)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xtkeejTQ6Cf)

Comment: Use Printf with the verb `%p`. Read more about verbs here: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ :

> Println formats using the default formats for its operands

If you want to print in a specific way, you need to use `fmt.Printf()` and supply the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

The [`fmt.Println(...)` function](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) "[uses] the default formats for its operands" and according to the [`fmt` package header documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing):

```
%v  the value in a default format
...
struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
...
pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
```

So the following lines are effectively the same:

```
fmt.Println(p, q)
fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", p, q)
```

If you want to print the memory address of a pointer then you should use the `%p` format verb:

```
Pointer:
%p  base 16 notation, with leading 0x
```

For example:

```
fmt.Printf("%p\n", q) // => 0x1953e4
```